# elasticsearch group by multi java api

Tags: elasticsearch

I have just used Elastic Search.
I want to complete this query using group by twice.
this is my elasticsearch query group by srcip under group by srcMac

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "gte": "now-7d/d",
        "lte": "now/d"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "id1_count": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "srcip"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "id2_count": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "srcMac"
          }
        },
        "aggs": {
          "sum": {
            "script": "doc['rcvd'].value + doc['sent'].value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is normally done.
But my java code is not correct.

This is my java code.

```
TermsAggregationBuilder termagg2 = AggregationBuilders.terms("id2_count").field("srcMac")
                // add the sum sub-aggregation
                .subAggregation(aggregation);

        TermsAggregationBuilder termagg = AggregationBuilders.terms("aggs").field("srcip").size(10) 
                    // add the second-level terms sub-aggregation
                   .subAggregation(termagg2);  

        SearchResponse sr = client.prepareSearch("coreit").setTypes("doc")
                .setQuery(qb)
                .addAggregation(termagg)
                .execute().actionGet();

        Terms terms = sr.getAggregations().get("aggs");
        for (Terms.Bucket bucket : terms.getBuckets()) {
            long cnt =bucket.getDocCount() ;
            Sum agg = bucket.getAggregations().get("agg");
            System.out.println(bucket.getKey()+" / cnt : "+cnt + " : sum : "+agg.getValue()  );
        }

        Terms terms2 = sr.getAggregations().get("aggs");
        for (Terms.Bucket bucket2 : terms2.getBuckets()) {
            System.out.println(bucket2.getKey());
        } << I think this part is error
```

I want see . srcip : ~~ / srcMac : ~~ / sum : ~~ 
what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to build your aggregations correctly:

```
    // build the inner-most sum aggregation
    SumAggregationBuilder aggregation = AggregationBuilders.sum("agg").script(sct);

    // build the second-level terms aggregation on srcMac
    TermsAggregationBuilder termagg2 = AggregationBuilders.terms("id2_count")
        .field("srcMac")
        // add the sum sub-aggregation
        .subAggregation(aggregation);

    // build the top-level terms aggregation
    TermsAggregationBuilder termagg = AggregationBuilders
       .terms("aggs")
       .field("srcip")
       .size(10)
        // add the second-level terms sub-aggregation
       .subAggregation(termagg2);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.
But I have an Invalid aggregator order path [agg]. Unknown aggregation [agg] error occurred. what's the agg? my Terms part is error?

Comment: Comment out the `order` call since you don't have it in your original query. What does it yield?

Comment: I remark .order~~ I use .setQuery(qb)
     .addAggregation(termagg)
     .execute().actionGet(); This part is error? or Terms part? error message is same

Comment: I updated my questions under java code , please check again